# Dependency gtools notavailable while installing MSA Package

Tags: r, failed-installation, installation-package

So I'm trying to install the Market Segmentation Analysis (MSA) package for a book I'm reading. The website that the book uses is here:

http://www.marketsegmentationanalysis.org/

On this website, I followed the instructions to install package MSA directly from the web page:

install.packages("https://homepage.boku.ac.at/leisch/MSA/packages/MSA_0.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

However, once I enter the code, the console is showing the following error (image attached):

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mESCI.png)

As a beginner to R, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if the MSA package is not compatible with my version of R (1.2.5019)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Install gtools first (you can use the tools menu in R Studio) and then install MSA from the archive itself, not from the CRAN.

Comment: Fantastic! Just installed gtools. What do you mean from the archive itself vs. CRAN? Thanks again

Comment: Download the .tar.gz file for MSA to your machine and then use the install package menu to install the package from the file your downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install gtools package before to install the MSA package.

```
install.packages("gtools")
install.packages("https://homepage.boku.ac.at/leisch/MSA/packages/MSA_0.3-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```